# How to write the text R outputs from a function to a file?

Tags: r, function, text, output

I have a function `custom_1` and when I use `print(custom_1)` R prints the returned data.frame but also some text at the bottom such as

> The final values used for the model were mtry = 10 and ntree = 250

What i want to do is print the data.frame and the text but every time I try to write to a file only the dataframe gets printed.

This is the code i've been using.

```
write.csv(print(custom_1), file="results2.csv")
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with some sample data and the desired output for that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `sink`. In your case:

```
sink("results2.csv") # open the connection
print(custom_1)
sink()               # close the connection
```

The `sink` function takes output that would ordinarily go to the console and writes it to the specified file.